# Can someone point out to me why ActiveRecord::Enum is not working as expected in this simple example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

I am implementing some code refactoring and for my purposes, I've determined that ActiveRecord::Enum would be a perfect fit. For those who have not used or heard of ActiveRecord::Enum here is the documentation link
[ActiveRecord::Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Here is code taken from the docs that I am having a problem with.

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
 enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
end

# conversation.update! status: 0
conversation.active!
conversation.active? # => true
conversation.status  # => "active"

# conversation.update! status: 1
conversation.archived!
conversation.archived? # => true
conversation.status    # => "archived"

# conversation.status = 1
conversation.status = "archived"

conversation.status = nil
conversation.status.nil? # => true
conversation.status      # => nil
```

Here is my example code which tries to mimic this behavior:

```
class ReverificationTracer < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum status: [ :verified, :unverified ]
end

rev = ReverificationTracker.create

rev.verified! ==> true
rev.unverified? ==> false
rev.status ==> nil

rev.unverified! ==> true
rev.unverified? ==> false
rev.status ==> nil
```

When I inspect the `rev` variable, I do see that the status has shifted to `'0'`

```
rev

id: 1,
account_id: nil,
status: "0",
created_at: Wed, 24 Feb 2016 16:24:55 UTC +00:00,
updated_at: Wed, 24 Feb 2016 16:25:21 UTC +00:00>
```

When it is archived I see the status increment to 1.

Why is this not working as I would expect from the documentation?

Comment: My guess is: your status column is to be integer, not string.

Comment: Are you trying to compare a string (value set was `'archived'`) to an array of symbols? There might be a type mismatch here, leading to a wrong validation

Comment: That was exactly it. I had to change the database column to integer not string. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by your `status` column being string column, not the integer. Change it to integer and everything will work as expected.